# How much gasoline in cubic meters is used per day?

Tags: gas

Many of us drive a car, trucks get driven each day and many other machines use gasoline as well. This gets pumped out of our earth continuously, making earth bit by bit more hallow. Not a real calculation, but seeing how many trucks I see just in my small country (The Netherlands) and extrapolate to the whole earth times the average gasoline usage per hour.. we should be thinking about small cities in cubic meters per day of gasoline usage.

That made me wondering.. What is the number a bit more exact? And could you give a relative estimate to compare that number to (like a football stadium).

*I don't care for an error margin of 5% or numbers from 2013. Just want something to 'grab' and get an idea.*

Comment: This question is a better fit for [Opendata.se]. Make sure to read [this](https://opendata.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/284/how-a-good-data-request-question-should-look-like), and [search](https://opendata.stackexchange.com/search?q=is%3Aq+gasoline) the site [first](https://opendata.stackexchange.com/search?q=is%3Aq+fuel). Then remove your question here (no crossposting across SE sites).

Answer (score 2):

The total consumption of crude oil according to this [site](http://www.indexmundi.com/energy/) is around 100 000 000 barrels per day and is in SI units 10 000 000 cubic meters. Of course not all of that can be processed to gasoline, but the scale of things is revealed. That would be actually bigger than a football stadium's volume a day as it would effectively be a cube with all sides around 215 meters.

Comment: 215m2 isn't that much actually. Surprised, as I thought it would be much higher.

Comment: Not $215m²$, but $10 000 000m^3 \approx 215m * 215m * 215m$.